# MySQL Loading Rows via String's Contents

Tags: mysql, database, string, join, database-design

I'm making a "Like" button for a portfolio website I'm working on and I've gotten stumped by some of my own code!

I have two MySQL tables:

- **img_all**: contains all images on the server (each image has a 6 *INT* id)
- **login**: contains account information for all users of the website (each user has a 6 *INT* id as well a *VARCHAR* column labeled "likes")

The way my system is laid out. When a user "Likes" a picture, I save that picture's id to a column on the login table.

```
UPDATE login SET likes = CONCAT(likes,':$img_id:') WHERE user_key = $user_id;
```

and when they unlike a picture:

```
UPDATE login SET likes = REPLACE(likes,':$img_id:','') WHERE user_key = $user_id;
```

This will output strings in the *likes* column similar to this:

```
:456093:475829:203944:789203:
```

My problem starts here. I'm making a page that allows users to view all the pictures that they've liked (let's call this file "Likes.php").
However, the list of liked pictures are saved in the *login* table, while the actual picture information is saved in *img_all*.

How then do I take the list from my *login* table and translate it to select those images from *img_all*? I was thinking of using a mixture of:

```
SELECT user_key FROM login WHERE likes LIKE '%:$img_id:%';
```

and

```
while();
```

I also thought of a SQL query. I know it won't work. However, hopefully, it will also help relay what I'm trying to accomplish!

```
SELECT * FROM
img_all WHERE id =
      SELECT likes FROM login
            WHERE likes LIKE '%:$img_id:%' AND user_key = '$user_id';
```

Comment: normalise that data, this is a poor design. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Comment: @tim Thanks for the comment! I actually haven't considered or heard of the 1NF,2NF ect! I'll be sure to redesign my tables accordingly. However, even if I do that, I'll still be faced with this same problem...

Comment: add likes table (user_id,image_id) then you can use a single join to easily display all a users likes

Comment: `SELECT * FROM img_all left join likes on img_all.id=likes.image_id WHERE user_id=XXX` this will give you all the images liked by the XXX person

Comment: "I'm sorry, you can't like any more images, because the string in your `likes` column is full. If you liked some images with lower id numbers, you can fit more into the string?" -- Tech Support responses we never want to hear

Comment: You guys are totally right! so, in my new likes table. I need to make a new row for every image that a user likes? I think that's what's got me a little confused, just because of how many possible duplicates of user_id and img_id this would create.

Comment: yes one row per user_id\image_id, you can make a unique key on both so you will get no duplicates. And dont worry about how many rows you get mysql is happy with many millions, this will scale, your current approach wont.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Instead of using a subquery, you can turn your query into a `JOIN`, like :

```
SELECT i.*
FROM img_all i
INNER JOIN login l ON l.likes LIKE CONCAT('%:', l.img_id, ':%')
WHERE user_id = ?
```

---

While this might solve your question, please be aware that storing list of values in a single column is almost always an indication of poor design.

Accessing and modifying the data requires to manipulate strings, which is uneasy to do with SQL, error-prone and quite inefficient. Also, as commented by [Bill Karwin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20860/bill-karwin), the number of likes that you can store for a single user is limited by the maximum size of the string column.

As commented by [tim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10051234/tim), you should use a separated table to store the `likes`, with foreign keys to the `login` and `img_all` tables.

```
CREATE TABLE likes (
    like_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id INT NOT NULL,
    img_id  INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (like_id),
    FOREIGN KEY fk_likes_login(user_id) REFERENCES login(user_id),
    FOREIGN KEY fk_likes_img(img_id) REFERENCES  img_all(img_id)
);
```

NB : the auto-incremented primary key is not strictly necessary, and could be replaced by a composite unique index on the two foreign keys.

Then you can retrieve all images that a user liked with a simple `JOIN`ed query :

```
SELECT i.*
FROM likes 
INNER JOIN img_all ON img_all.img_id = likes.img_id
WHERE likes.user_id = ?
```

Comment: you dont even need a  `like_id` thers nothing you will ever be doing with it, just a unique index on both and a index for each will cover all options

Comment: Thanks for the extra info! I'm really happy I asked, otherwise I wouldn't have even heard about 1NF until I went to college!

Comment: @tim : well there are different schools of thaught on this matter... But anyway you are correct in the sense that the auto pk is not strictly necessary here, I updated my answer to make it explicit.